# bash read string formatting

Tags: string, bash, rsync

Trying to assign input from user to a variable `SRC`.

In text editor:
read -p "5. Drag and drop the folder containing your short name into this window. Press 'return' AFTER you drop the folder here:  " SRC
cd $SRC

In terminal:
`/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Users/fakeperson` (this path is being assigned to SRC)

However, when I echo $SRC, I get this:
`/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/fakeperson` (no backslash after HD)

and I can't

```
 cd /Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/fakeperson
```

Ultimately, I want this one line to work

```
rsync -raz --progress $SRC $HOME
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

back slash is taken as an escape character for space.. if you want backslash after `HD` you need to escape the backslash using another `backslash` so you need to enter

`/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\\\ 1/Users/fakeperson`

to assign src as

`/Volumes/Macintosh HD\ 1/Users/fakeperson`

It's always a good idea to give the string input in `double quotes` which has spaces and special characters like `\` rather than escaping them. You can simply give the input as :

```
"/Volumes/Macintosh HD\ 1/Users/fakeperson"
```

Comment: this is very close. However, I'm trying to have minimal interaction after assigning the file path to SRC. Any command to append the backslashes automatically?

Comment: @bskillets ok.. I got your point.. there is no command to assign back slashes automatically... put the variable `$SRC` under double quotes wherever it is used in our script..  `cd "$src"`  this will solve most of your problem..